# how to insert download links in HTML5 for non-standard extension types

Tags: html, hyperlink

I'm a complete beginner at HTML, and have started learning the basics in HMTL5.

I found code to insert download links in HTML5 like this:

```
<a href="myfileuniquename.zip" download="myfile">Download Myfile</a>
```

This works fine with standard extensions like .png and .zip, but when i try .rar (as per RarLab) the files are downloading as .txt:

```
<a href="myfileuniquename.rar" download="myfile">Download Myfile</a>
```

--> this downloads myfileuniquename.rar but downloads it as myfile.txt

How do I fix this so non-standard file extensions are preserved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `download` attribute, if present, indicates that the author intends the hyperlink to be used for downloading a resource. The attribute may have a value; the value, if any, specifies the default file name that the author recommends for use in labeling the resource in a local file system. There are no restrictions on allowed values, but authors are cautioned that most file systems have limitations with regard to what punctuation is supported in file names, and user agents are likely to adjust file names accordingly.

http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/links.html#attr-hyperlink-download